# Just want to get the row number where my unique-id equals 102

Tags: google-apps-script

hi guys I am using Google App Script on a spreadsheet and I have a column where it is labeled unique id. I want to simply be able to get the row number where the unique id = HB-048

is there a simple way to do this as app script online examples are hard to find. basically once I get the row number where id = HB-048 I want to change the value of a cell. Kind of like you would in a database I suppose. Any help would be great!

The current code I am using which i think works is:

```
function Approve(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
var r = s.getRange('A1:ZZ');
var v = r.getValues();
var searchTerm = 'HB-048';
for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    if(v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
        Logger.log('ROW FOUND');
    }
}
};
```

Updated Code:

```
function Approve(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const s = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
const r = s.getRange('A1:ZZ');
const [hA, ...v] = r.getValues();
const searchTerm = 'HB-048';
let col = {};
hA.forEach((h,i) => col[h] = i+1);
for (var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
  if (v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > +1) {
  Logger.log('ROW:' + Number(i + 1));
  s.getRange( i + 1, col['Approval'] ).setValue('Approved')
  }
}
}
```

Comment: maby get the data as a json, update them post the data to upload the file?depends if is too large file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Approve() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const s = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
  const r = s.getRange('A1:ZZ');
  const [hA, ...v] = r.getDisplayValues();
  const searchTerm = 'HB-048';
  let col = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => col[h] = i + 1);
  for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    if (~v[i][0].indexOf(searchTerm)) {
      Logger.log('ROW:' + Number(i + 2));
      s.getRange(i + 2, col['Approval']).setValue('to whatever you want');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that worked so now is it possible once you have that row to change a cell in a column labeled Approved on that row?

Comment: Sure, what's the header row?

Comment: if you mean where the columns headers are then that is 1, and the name of the column is Approval

Comment: that bottom function worked but updated every single row even the header

Comment: Well then you have some debugging to do.

Comment: ok, not sure what to look at because now it does not log the row number either

Comment: That's all part of debugging.  If you want to write code you have to learn how to debug the code you write.

Comment: If you look at my updated code it gets the row but its putting the text on the line above, so if i look for searchterm hb-049 it puts the text on the line where hb-048 is

Comment: I tested this on my data and it works for me

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks i got it too work in the end, thanks for all your help guys!